# Как эффективно учить язык?

Tags: c++

Всем привет. Я начал изучать язык программирования c++ . Но у меня в голове ничего не остаётся. Есть какой нибудь способ  избавится от этого?

Comment: Как можно "избавиться" от того, от чего и так "ничего не остаётся"?

Comment: От головы? :) А всерьез - все тут же применяйте на практике. После пары тысяч строк с использованием новых знаний они закрепятся, никуда не денутся...

Comment: Возможно, программирование не для вас.

Comment: Этого может быть )

Answer (score 1):

Cразу практиковать то, что учишь))
И писать что-то весёлое

Comment: Вроде все хорошо получилось до массива. после пассива голова ничего соображает. и даже массивы не понимаю.

Comment: массив = это коробка с с чем либо, дескриптор (указатель) - это грубо говоря точные координаты массисы (коробки), причем указываюище на первый элемент (вещь из коробки)

Comment: А вообще возьми учебник с примерами либо бери примеры из инета и делай сам

Comment: спасибо вам )))